# Abrir Login Facebook de acordo com plataforma

Tags: php, facebook, login, sdk

Estou usando o SDK - PHP para fazer login no Facebook, quando acesso por um PC ele abre o site do facebook normal, mas quando abre pelo celular ele abre o site pelo navegador também. Tem como fazer ele abrir o aplicativo se o usuário estiver pelo celular e depois de logar, retornar ao navegador?

Comment: Não. A menos que você desenvolva um aplicativo nativo que mande o comando para o facebook.

Comment: Reforço o que o @juniorb2ss disse, se você abre seu site em um navegador mobile ele vai abrir o login do fb também dentro do navegador. Agora se quiser fazer aquele login nativo, vou te dar essa dica, tente construir um app para seu site usando o ionic framework.

Comment: Você testou o HybridAuth (http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/)? Aguardo um retorno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível! Para acessar o facebook no navegador do celular é necessário o usuário estar logado no próprio navegador. Não tem como o navegador interagir com o aplicativo do facebook. A única forma é você criar um aplicativo híbrido com o [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) ou [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) para poder logar pelo próprio aplicativo sem precisar estar logado no navegador. Espero ter ajudado!